# Computer modern bright font ignoring \textbf for small font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize, bold

In my document with a font size of 6pt, bold text isn't typeset correctly. The text gets only bold, when I change the size to 8pt, which is not my desired format. Is there any solution or workaround to this problem?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 6pt, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel} %choose your language
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amscd, amsmath, amssymb, blindtext, empheq, enumitem, multicol, parskip}
\usepackage{cmbright,bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Bold}\\
    Not Bold\\
    $\mathbf{Bold}$\\
    $Not Bold$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that `\large` doesn't take an argument, instead it is a switch and should be used inside a group like this: `{\large Not Bold}`. Also note that `german` is using the old German orthography, nowadays one should use `ngerman` instead.

Comment: The `cmbright` package is the culprit. Don't load it unless you (a) absolutely need it and (b) know what you're doing.

Comment: Also one shouldn't use `\bf` and if one uses it, it is a switch like `\large` and doesn't take an argument. Instead you could use `\mathbf` (which takes an argument) in maths.

Comment: @Mico I'd like the text to be in the computer modern font, so the package is essential for that, isn't it?

Comment: @Juan no, Computer Modern is the default font in TeX, `cmbright` is not Computer Modern, but Computer Modern Bright, which is a sans-serif typeface based on Computer Modern. To use Computer Modern, just don't use any font packages.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, then I meant to use Computer Modern Bright...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design. cmbright substitutes the normal font for fontsizes below 9pt. If you switch to T1-encoding (which is better anyway) you will get semi bold:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 6pt, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Bold}\\
    Not Bold\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Side remark: 6pt font is a pain for readers. So better avoid it ...